# KeyError: 'true ' error when i try to convert labels to 0 and 1

Tags: python, dataframe, nlp, pytorch, label

I am using Arabert (pre trained Bert for Arabic language) for binary classification labeled as true and false, i am trying to change the labels from "true" and "false" to 0 and one i used the code:

```
import pandas as pd

Data=pd.read_csv("/content/500-instances.csv")
DATA_COLUMN = 'sent'
LABEL_COLUMN = 'label'
Data.columns = [DATA_COLUMN, LABEL_COLUMN]
label_map = {
    'fake' : 0,
    'true' : 1
}

Data[DATA_COLUMN] = Data[DATA_COLUMN].apply(lambda x: preprocess(x, do_farasa_tokenization=False, use_farasapy = False))
Data[LABEL_COLUMN] = Data[LABEL_COLUMN].apply(lambda x: label_map[x])
```

i get an error: KeyError: 'true ' in the last line.

Do you have any solution?!
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These is a trailing space in `'true '`, that's why there is no match in `label_map`, try:

```
Data[LABEL_COLUMN] = Data[LABEL_COLUMN].apply(lambda x: label_map[x.strip()])
```

**EDIT**

If you are not sure what lies in `Data[LABEL_COLUMN]`, I would suggest catching unknown values with a default output value using `label_map.get(x.strip(), <DEFAULT_VALUE>)`.

Comment: this removed the previous error, but now I have this error: KeyError: 'label'

Comment: Then you better check what is in `Data[LABEL_COLUMN]`.
`Data[LABEL_COLUMN].value_counts()`

Comment: That work, i figured out there is wrong value in my dataset, Thank you :)